# How can I return a view(model) and also pass a query string param to the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC app where users fill in a 4-step form then go to a "confirm" screen. On the confirm screen, if they select to modify their info I use RedirectToAction to take them back to the first step view, and I pass a URL parameter "modify=true", which tells the controller to use the session object already created as opposed to creating a new object from the DB and displaying an empty form. But once they submit the form for step 1 I want to send them from my controller to the step 2 view along with the "modify=true" parameter. There doesn't seem to be a way to return a viewmodel to a view and also pass a query string parameter. How can I accomplish this?
I have considered adding a bool to the viewmodels to signify "inReview" but i use different viewmodels for each of these views and they're all pretty clean, it seems like this bool would muck things up a bit.

I have also considered adding the bool to viewbag or viewdata, but then i'd be using the submit button to pass that value and the "modify=true" parameter would drop off the URL, possibly confusing the user and definitely confusing the code.
Thanks

Comment: Can't you save it in a session variable? Set the variable to true when the user clicks 'modify' and set it to false when the user finishes the form.

Comment: well i'm using an action link w/ url string parameter to get them back to step 1. I could just set it in session once it redirects to step 1 but it would seem cleaner if i could just keep passing that url along instead.

Comment: Is the user authenticated or anonymous? When the user comes back, is the form supposed to be filled? Or does the user fills the form every time [he logs in]?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `Html.BeginForm()` helper (without parameters) it will automatically append existing query string parameters to the generated form `action` attribute. If you use some of the other overloads such as `Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", FormMethod.Post)` then you're gonna lose those parameters. This could be easily *fixed* by writing a custom helper that will take into account those parameters:

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static IDisposable BeginRequestForm(this HtmlHelper html, string action, string controller, FormMethod method)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("form");
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);

        var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
        var query = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
        foreach (string key in query)
        {
            routeValues[key] = query[key];
        }

        builder.MergeAttribute("action", urlHelper.Action(action, controller, routeValues));
        builder.MergeAttribute("method", HtmlHelper.GetFormMethodString(method), true);
        html.ViewContext.Writer.Write(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
        return new MvcForm(html.ViewContext);
    }
}
```

and then use in your view (after bringing it into scope of course):

```
@using (Html.BeginRequestForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: that works but how can i add object htmlAttributes to this method?          public static IDisposable BeginRequestForm(this HtmlHelper html, string action, string controller, FormMethod method, object htmlAttributes)

Comment: i just found out         builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes),true);

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `ViewBag` or your view model. You just need to pass the value somehow to the view:

```
ViewBag.modify = true;
return View(model);
```

Then in your view:

```
Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new { modify = ViewBag.modify })
```